# Some webpages timeout in multiple browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, dns, browser, timeout

Some websites take a long time loading, and eventually timeout before showing the page. Other websites are loaded without delay.
This happens in FF, Chrome and IE, on Windows 8 to the same sites. Closing the browser doesn't work either.
As far as I know I don't have javascript blockers or other addons. I've got a regular DHCP-address without proxy, nothing fancy. It also happens to sites without flash animations.
Once i tried the command *ipconfig /flushdns*, this solved the problem for a while, but it came back a few days later.
The computer next to it does not have this problem. Therefore it can't be a DNS/router/firewall/ISP-issue or a webserver down.

Does anybody know how to fix this (permanently)?

Cheers, Barry

Comment: My wife has this issue on her machine yet I don't on the same site. I believe the issue is due to PC spec in her case. Try and run a small script and see if fails. Or use chrome debugger to see of any exceptions... Is the other PC more powerful (CPU)

Comment: In Firefox go to Options -> Developer --> Network (Ctrl+Shift+Q). Click on "Reload" and you can watch what is loading and the timing. You can also open Browser Console (Ctrl+Shift+J) in case some other activity such as antivirus software action is happening. Since you say "some websites", you really need to add some examples to your question.

Comment: Thanks, 
One of the sites is the Office 365 portal (https://login.microsoftonline.com). The Ctrl+Shift+Q trick shows some of the pictures taking 19 seconds to load!?!
Same thing is happening at another location, after upgrading to Windows 10. Could this be due to IPv6?
Found some sites advising to disable Windows Firewall and using a different DNS server. I'm gonna try that, and disable IPv6.

Comment: Hi guys, this problem has disappeared without changing anything. I'm gonna blame this on some unknown glitch in my providers DNS and close this topic. Thanks for helping.